# How can i make not allow column to allow null and Allow Null column to not allow null

Tags: sql-server-2008

Could any one help me to perform below task.

How can i make not allow column to allow null and Allow Null column to not allow null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype [NOT] NULL`

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Foo
(
X INT NULL,
Y INT NOT NULL
)

/*This is metadata only change and very quick*/
ALTER TABLE #Foo ALTER COLUMN Y INT  NULL

/*This requires all rows to be scanned to validate the data*/
ALTER TABLE #Foo ALTER COLUMN X INT NOT NULL
```

Comment: What if the data exist in the table before.

Comment: To make the column allow `NULL` then makes no difference. If making `NOT NULL` then need to `UPDATE` any values that are `NULL` first or the `ALTER TABLE` will fail